# A synonym for good in "good cooperation"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am currently writing a report in which I need to mention the cooperation between people. Is there a better word used to describe cooperation, instead of *good*?

This is because I feel *good* is too basic to use here. I tried to look in a dictionary. In my opinion, the following are not suitable to describe cooperation:

> *beneficial*, *advantageous*, *proficient*, *capable*, *acceptable*, and *skillful*

Which word could I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible add another dimension.

**[Consistent](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consistent)** cooperation (as oposed to intermittent/ spasmodic)

[**Productive**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/productive?q) cooperation.  But if the outcome is not yet clear...

**[Promising](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/productive?q)** cooperation will yield results at some time in the future.

All links to the Cambridge Dictionary on line.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP doesn't want to use the words "good cooperation" in this context then may I suggest "team spirit", "corporate team spirit" or "work ethic" among the workers, staff, colleagues, department or whichever collective noun is applicable to the context. For example, one might write, "There is a great sense of team spirit among the staff".

TEAM SPIRIT: Willingness to cooperate as part of a team. (FreeDictionary - online)

Answer (score 0):

There can be many adjectives synonymous with *good* which can precede *cooperation*, but it's difficult to pinpoint one without enough context.

Assuming you are looking for an adjective implying the cooperation is *good* in the context of *achieving the common goal*, I suggest ***harmonious***.

Cambridge Dictionary:

> [**harmonious**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/harmonious) adjective (PLEASANT)
>
> friendly and peaceful:
>
> harmonious relations between the country's ethnic groups

Usage examples: [A Google search for "harmonious cooperation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=harmonious%20cooperation&rct=j)